# Set default textbox value that can't be removed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, vb.net

All values for a text box begin with `T-`

how do I have a textbox prepopulated with `T-` where the user cannot remove the `T-`

Thanks for your help

Comment: Simplest thing off the top of my head would be to have `T-` as static text to the left of the textbox, and process the text before setting/getting the value

Comment: thanks for your reply, thats what was thinking as well guess its the simplest way!

Comment: My gut feeling is that you could spend a HUGE amount of time trying to figure out some clever javascript/jquery and still miss some situation where the user could remove it.  The other option would be to add a `<asp:RegularExpressionValidator>` to check it starts with it, but obviously that doesn't stop them removing it, just from submitting the form

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
<input id="field" type="text" value="T-" size="50" />
```

JS

```
var readOnlyLength = $('#field').val().length;

 $('#output').text(readOnlyLength);

$('#field').on('keypress, keydown', function(event) {
    var $field = $(this);
    $('#output').text(event.which + '-' + this.selectionStart);
    if ((event.which != 37 && (event.which != 39))
        && ((this.selectionStart < readOnlyLength)
        || ((this.selectionStart == readOnlyLength) && (event.which == 8)))) {
        return false;
    }
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/u5qSY/)

Comment: every text box generate html pass that `id` here

Answer (score 0):

Attach the label before the textbox and give textbox left-border to 0px and label right-border to 0px. While getting the value add both the values. hope it helps you.